# http request has been block from https

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, nginx, cross-domain

I have one issue below:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.example.com/api/demo.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It's work fine when request from 'https://example.com' to 'http://api.example.com/api/demo.php'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mixed content warning and is a bad practice. [See below from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent)

> When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their connection with the
>   web server is encrypted with TLS and hence safeguarded from sniffers
>   and man-in-the-middle attacks.
>
> If the HTTPS page includes content retrieved through regular,
>   cleartext HTTP, then the connection is only partially encrypted: the
>   unencrypted content is accessible to sniffers and can be modified by
>   man-in-the-middle attackers, and therefore the connection is not
>   safeguarded anymore. When a webpage exhibits this behavior, it is
>   called a mixed content page.

You should either;

- Modify to use the https endpoint or
- proxy the request as https.

Comment: Using a protocol-relative URL for the AJAX call (and any other resource) is one way to 'trivially fix' this issue.