# okhttp3 error Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp

I Working a Java API client class that makes a call to a server
this calls working as expected when running locally - but when I run them in Kubernetes they failed with the below error

Do I need to specify a JVM options for working with SSL?
I'm running a main class no spring is used.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:451)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1493)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1399)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:446)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:417)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happends becouse you are talking to an HTTP server, not an HTTPS server. You should try:

- Check the port number
- Modify to use one HTTP endpoint
- Proxy the request as HTTPS

Check this out:

- [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)
- [Http request has been block from https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676041/http-request-has-been-block-from-https)